# Adding value to String[] android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to have an example `String[] images` like the below dynamically, but i cannot achieve it

```
String[] images = new String[] { "http://image/image1", "http://image/image1", "http://image/image1"};
```

I have a json where it contains the image urls, below code is how i am tryig to put the json image urls to the `string[] images`

```
 String[] images = new String[]{};

 for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

     String imagepath = c.getString("imagepath");

     images[i] = imagepath; // trying to put the values to String[] images
     }
```

Comment: You need to specify the length of your array when you create it.

Comment: What is that `newURL` you may need to assign `imagepath`  right ?

Comment: sorry im assigning `imagepath` not the `newURL`

Comment: Consider to accept any answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int lenth=contacts.length();

String[] images = new String[lenth];

 for (int i = 0; i < lenth; i++) {
     JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

     String imagepath = c.getString("imagepath");

     images[i] = imagepath ; // trying to put the values to String[] images
     }
```

For better looping follow [Performance Tips](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/articles/perf-tips.html) .

Answer (score 3):

try using Arraylist instead of array

```
 ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            String imagepath = c.getString("imagepath");

            arraylist.add(imagepath);
        }
```

to retrive item use arraylist.get(i);

Answer (score 2):

You must define a size for your `String[]` before using it.

```
String[] images = new String[contacts.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
    String imagepath = c.getString("imagepath");
    images[i] = newURL; // trying to put the values to String[] images
}
```

Comment: What is the length / content of `contacts` ?

Comment: contacts is `JSONArray` which i get from httpclient

Comment: Did you check that `contacts` is not empty ?